# function definition in javascript. But what is the actual difference?

Tags: javascript

I am a java programmer with 15 years experience, but I am struggling to get my head around javascript.  Below is an example and I am keen to understand the differences between the 2 definitions.

Are these 2 definitions very different or would either be acceptable if I want to create object instances of Subject?

```
var Subject1 = ( function( window, undefined ) {

  function Subject1() {
    this._list = [];
  }

  // this method will handle adding observers to the internal list
  Subject1.prototype.observe = function observeObject( obj ) {
    console.log( 'added new observer' );
    this._list.push( obj );
  };

  Subject1.prototype.unobserve = function unobserveObject( obj ) {
    for( var i = 0, len = this._list.length; i < len; i++ ) {
      if( this._list[ i ] === obj ) {
        this._list.splice( i, 1 );
        console.log( 'removed existing observer' );
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  Subject1.prototype.notify = function notifyObservers() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 0 );
    for( var i = 0, len = this._list.length; i < len; i++ ) {
      this._list[ i ].update.apply( null, args );
    }
  };

  return Subject1;

} )( window );


//Subject2 example but based on the revealing module design pattern.

function Subject2() {
  this._list = [];

  // this method will handle adding observers to the internal list
  function observeObject( obj ) {
    console.log( 'added new observer' );
    this._list.push( obj );
  }

  function unobserveObject( obj ) {
    for( var i = 0, len = this._list.length; i < len; i++ ) {
      if( this._list[ i ] === obj ) {
        this._list.splice( i, 1 );
        console.log( 'removed existing observer' );
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function notifyObservers() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 0 );
    for( var i = 0, len = this._list.length; i < len; i++ ) {
      this._list[ i ].update.apply( null, args );
    }
  }

  return {
    notifyObservers : notifyObservers,
    unobserveObject : unobserveObject,
    observeObject   : observeObject
  }
}
```

So now we have the function definitions of Subject1  and Subject2 what are the material differences if I was to then do

```
var subject1 = new Subject1();
var subject2 = new Subject2();
```

both definitions have exactly the same functionality and do the same thing, but what are their key differences that I need to be aware of?

Thanks

Comment: one makes per-instance props/methods, the other makes inherited props/methods

Comment: So you are asking what the difference between the revealing module pattern and JS constructor/prototype - based solutions are?

Comment: If that is what the difference is then yes I suppose I am asking that exact question.

Comment: @dandavis do you want the OP to guess which one is which?  ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `Subject2` does not work due to the way you access the `._list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Subject1 definition is defining functions on the prototype chain of the object, whereas the Subject2 definition is simply defining functions for that object.

The difference comes when you instantiate a new object. When you instantiate a new Subject1 object, you will still only have one instance of all its functions in memory, because they exist on the prototype chain of Subject1. However, every time you instantiate a Subject2 object, you are also creating new instances of all the functions defined for Subject2, because they are defined for each instance of Subject2.

Comment: Just to clarify the situation here.  If you know that you will only ever have a single instance of the named Object eg Subject1 or Subject2 is it still deemed incorrect to define the function as that defined in Subject2?

Comment: @juckky Generally speaking, it is a good idea to define functions on the prototype if you're going to be creating a lot of instances for the object. A use case for not defining methods on the prototype of the object is if you're going to be using local "private" variables that you would like to be unique to each instance of the object in the method you want to define.

Comment: if you will only have a single instance, it makes no sense to go to the trouble of using a constructor, just use an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet offers (arguably) a more traditional object-oriented approach. The additional braces at the beginning and at the end of the big **Subject1** function mean that it will get invoked immediately when the program starts. What this function does is 1) to register the object methods and 2) return the small **Subject1** function, which is the actual constructor. So when you do **new Subject1();** you are actually just creating the list - the methods are already defined.

The second snippet differs from the first one in many ways. It creates a new copy of the methods for each new object, so objects created with this approach occupy a little more memory. But as an exchange for that you get more flexibility: you can have private variables (by declaring them with var instead of attaching them to the object). You can have private functions (you just don't return them) and construct new functions programmatically.

Comment: Thanks.  Coming from a java development background where encapsulation and hiding data is the name of the game Subject2 seems more intuitive.